# Will 'private' status prevent Woocommerce products to be indexed by search engines?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, private, search-engines, noindex

I'm currently disabling some Woocommerce product from my site and for this, I set them as `private`.

I'd like to know if 'private' will **also** set the `no index` meta as true?

Comment: If you are using the default Wordpress method of marking a post/page private,  **NO**.  This only prevents that post/page content from being viewable.  It will prompt the user for a password. So, Google (and other search bots) would still index it, but only that prompt.  No content would be indexed, but `no index` would not be added..

Comment: Thanks. If you want, put your comment as an answer for me to qualify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the default Wordpress method of marking a post/page private, NO. This only prevents that post/page content from being viewable.

Google (and other search bots) will not find [private pages](https://en.support.wordpress.com/post-and-page-visibility/).  Only logged in  blog Editors and Administrators can see Private pages.

So, while Wordpress will not add the meta to block bots, your private pages still will be invisible to Search Engines.

Comment: This is not correct. Private pages do not ask for a password, and if a page is private then it returns a 404 to logged out users, so it would not be indexed.

Comment: My apologies.  I got in a hurry and spewed information about "Password Protected" pages, instead of "Private" pages.  I have corrected my answer.